# How maven looks for a jar on the local machine?

Tags: maven-2, maven, pom.xml, maven-war-plugin

I have the following pom.xml configured for my project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <!-- The Basics -->

    <groupId>fcrt.fcBase.MyProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>My Project</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>  

    <!-- Build Settings -->

        <build>
        <plugins>
         <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <webXml>web.xml</webXml>
              <webResources>
                  <resource>
                      <filtering>true</filtering>
                      <directory>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF</directory>
                      <includes>
                          <include>**/*.xml</include>
                      </includes>
                  </resource>
              </webResources>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build> 
 </project>
```

However since I am using maven-2.0.5 version, I would have to use maven-war-plugin-2.0.jar instead of maven-war-plugin-2.1.1.jar because of compatibilty issues.
While creating war, I am getting the below error:

**[INFO] Internal error in the plugin manager executing goal 'org.apache.maven.plu
gins:maven-war-plugin:2.0:war': Unable to find the mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugin
s:maven-war-plugin:2.0:war' in the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-pl
ugin'**

Is there any way so that the maven looks for the jar on my local(since I have it on my local) if it is not able to download it from the apache site? Also please confirm if the pom.xml I have is correct?

Comment: So, what you want, is to use `maven-war-plugin-2.0` (downgrading from `2.1.1`) with `maven-2.0.5`? I've checked the dependencies: `maven-war-plugin-2.1.1` depends on `maven-plugin-api-2.0.6` and `maven-war-plugin-2.0` depends on `maven-plugin-api-2.0` – probably this triggers the issue.

Comment: what is the command you use? `mvn war`?

Answer (score 0):

Try the offline option of Maven (mvn -o)...btw. really old maven version 2.0. The most up-to-date is there 2.0.11 and furthermore i would recommend to update to Maven 3 asap.

Comment: -o option doesn't work since I have nowhere configured that maven looks for the jar on local as I dont know how to do that. Any idea?. n yeah 2.0 is old bt dont have a choice since its the project requirement n its pretty old one

Comment: -o option will bring Maven into Off-Line mode and will not go outside. but the error message looks like something different is wrong. Maven looks local in your local repository ${HOME}/.m2/repository first before it tries to go to Maven Central or anywhere else configured (Maven Repository Manager ?)

Comment: I think its a problem with the way I've setup maven on my local. All I did it downloaded maven-2.0.5 on my local, set up few env variables and then created pom.xml. No where I have location such as ${HOME}/.m2/repository on my local. Can you please guide what are the steps to configure local repository?

Comment: Yes, but `-o` will not work in case one needs to `mvn deploy`.

Comment: @Khmarbaise Hey I have this repository on my local, was just a stupid mistake while setting variables, but still I am getting the same error. Looking at the error its looking for maven-war-plugin 2.0 war. Shouldn't it be a jar it is looking for?

Comment: Try to removed the local repository part .m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins and retry it. Cause i tested it and it works perfect. So the problem must be either a problem with your local repository or with your settings.xml etc.

Comment: @khmarbaise in my settings.xml I have <settings>
localRepository
   | The path to the local repository maven will use to store artifacts.
   |
   | Default: ~/.m2/repository
  <localRepository>D:/Documents and Settings/a.buzz/.m2/repository</localRepository></settings>

Comment: @buzz3110 delete the plugins/ directory as @khmarbaise said. Then, run `mvn install`, and check whether the m-war-p got downloaded to that directory. That way, you can make sure that your local repo is active!